# Help with login to site with PHP + cURL

Tags: php, forms, post, curl, authentication

I was looking for help with a problem I have using cURL to get info from a site.

I'm a newbie using cURL, so I need some guidance with this. I need to login to 3dstats.com automatically and then recover a list of data. With the list there's no problem, I'm already working on a solution; it's the login that I can't get to work. The login form, after much cleaning up, is something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content=
    "HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="2" />
      <input type="text" class="flinput" size="40" name="usr" value="00000000" />
      <input type="password" size="40" name="UsrPass" class="flinput" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit " class="binput" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, I need to send 3 variables, type, usr, and UsrPass. If I save this page and click Submit, the form works fine (after changing the fields to hidden and populating them with the correct login values, of course).
However, if I do this:

```
<?php  
  $ch     = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://3dstats.com/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

  $data   = array("type"    => "44",
                  "usr"     => "correct8-digitNumber",
                  "UsrPass" => "correctPassword");

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  '/3dstats/cookies.txt');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/3dstats/cookies.txt');

   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   $info   = curl_getinfo($ch);

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($info);
   echo "</pre>";

   echo $output;

   curl_close($ch);
?>
```

the form returns: "Error : Wrong Account", with the account number already populated to " 0000" (note the space). The account is an 8-digit number.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? The page says it is using cookies. What is the correct form of capturing/using them later? What I'm trying doesn't seem to be working.
Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question and for future reference, the way it worked was like this:

```
$cookie_file_path = getcwd() . '/cookie.txt';
//Emulating Chrome Browser:
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/A.B (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/X.Y.Z.W Safari/A.B.";

/*  Login part of the code -- start */

//First, get and write session cookie:
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://3dstats.com/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path);

$loginpage_html = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

//Now, use the session cookie to actually log in:
$POSTFIELDS = "type=44&usr=". $your_username ."&UsrPass=". $your_password;  

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://3dstats.com/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://3dstats.com/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path);

$logon_result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

The login now works.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem a few days back, the solution I found to be the simplest and easiest to deal with technically was asking the site owner to make that page you are trying to access public display. More information would help if you told us if that site is yours or an external site you are trying to fetch the data from.

Comment: The site I'm trying to get the info from is not mine. I'm coding a crawler to make visitor info reports from 3dstats.com, which is the site I'm attempting to login into. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is:  login into 3dstats.com using my username/password.  Once logged in, manipulate the query string to get the reports I need.  Then, get the HTML and extract the info needed to make the reports.