# issue logging in to website using curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I need to login into a website to scrap data but I am unable to login.
Below is my code

Form in which I need to Put Values

```
<FORM id=form1 style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff" name=form1 action="http://120.146.143.32/cgi-bin/APWPW.EXE" method=post>
<SPAN style="WIDTH: 715px; POSITION: relative; HEIGHT: 295px">
<SPAN id=text1 style="FONT-SIZE: 40px; LEFT: 130px; WIDTH: 490px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 30px; HEIGHT: 20px">
<P>Welcome to Online Ordering</P></SPAN>
<SPAN id=text2 style="LEFT: 130px; WIDTH: 110px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 110px; HEIGHT: 20px">
<P>Your Account #</P></SPAN>
<SPAN id=text3 style="LEFT: 130px; WIDTH: 110px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 150px; HEIGHT: 20px">
<P>Password</P></SPAN>
<SPAN name=account style="LEFT: 260px; WIDTH: 166px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 110px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff00"> APW146 </SPAN>
<INPUT id=password1 style="LEFT: 260px; WIDTH: 168px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 150px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff00" type=password value="" name=password1>
<SPAN id=text4 style="LEFT: 10px; WIDTH: 300px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 260px; HEIGHT: 20px">
<P>Keyin your Password then press enter</P></SPAN>
<INPUT id=inputimage1 style="LEFT: 460px; WIDTH: 200px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 90px; HEIGHT: 170px" type=image src="http:/cobol/APW.JPG" name=inputimage1>
<INPUT type=hidden name=hpath value=\APW\>
<INPUT type=hidden name=haccount value=APW146>
</SPAN>
</FORM>
```

Here is my Curl function to Login

```
    function login(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://120.146.143.32/cgi-bin/APWPW.EXE');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://120.146.143.32/cgi-bin/APW.EXE'); //login URL

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REDIRECT_URL,'http://120.146.143.32/cgi-bin/APW.EXE');


   $user = array(
        'account' => 'APW146',
        'haccount'=>'APW146',
        'password1'=>'',
        'inputimage1.x' => '0',
        'inputimage1.y' => '0',
        'hpath' =>'\APW\\'


    );

   print_r($user);
   //echo "\APW\\";
   // echo $postData;
    //exit();
   // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('password1=XXXXXXXX&inputimage1.x=0&inputimage1.y=0&hpath=%5CAPW%5C&haccount=APW146')); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $user);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $store = curl_exec ($ch);
   // header("Set-Cookie:__utma=176595493.25749725.1353988994.1353988994.1353988994.1");
    header("Set-Cookie:__utmz=176595493.1353988994.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);Set-Cookie:__utma=176595493.25749725.1353988994.1353988994.1353988994.1");

  // print_r($store);








   var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
  //  echo $store;
  //exit();

    return $ch;


}
```

OUtput I get when I do var_dump

```
array (size=22)
  'url' => string 'http://120.146.143.32/cgi-bin/APW.EXE' (length=37)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html' (length=9)
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 197
  'request_size' => int 226
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 0.187
  'namelookup_time' => float 0
  'connect_time' => float 0.062
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0.062
  'size_upload' => float 659
  'size_download' => float 1703
  'speed_download' => float 9106
  'speed_upload' => float 3524
  'download_content_length' => float 1703
  'upload_content_length' => float 659
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.109
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
```

output from var_dump($store);

```
string '<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE></TITLE>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">

<META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="FUJITSU NetCOBOL">



<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript>



function body1_onload_func()

{

if (document.form1.hbalances.value=="Y")

document.form1.submit5.style.visibility="visible"

else

document.form1.submit5.style.visibility="hidden"

}



function onclick_func_b1()

{

document.form1.hchoice.value="SA"

}

function onclick_func_b2()

{

document.form1.hchoice.value="OS"

}

function oncli'... (length=2710)
```

I can't give out the password of the account for security reasons.

Thanks
Ab

Comment: You missed an escaping backslash in $user. `'hpath' =>'\APW\\'` should be `'hpath' =>'\\APW\\'`

Comment: Also, what is the exact problem you're having? "I am unable to login" is not very descriptive. Are you getting an error message somewhere?

Comment: I don't seem to get any error.  But when I try to load the page which I can access after logging in it says  "Invalid Account". This message popups when I set the password wrong or set any other post parameters wrong.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the password out.

Comment: You see where it says "password1=XXXXXXX" in your post? That used to be your password. I edited it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

the actual html output from the server should be in here:

```
 $store = curl_exec ($ch);
```

do a **var_dump($store)** and see what you get

Comment: I added the output of var_dump($store) above in the question.

Comment: Well you are POST'ing to the wrong url.  Try post to  ['http://120.146.143.32/cgi-bin/APWPW.EXE'](http://120.146.143.32/cgi-bin/APWPW.EXE)

Comment: Hi,
I have tried using both URL. ie  both form.php and post.php  as I was confused. But still results is the same. I have posted all the hidden values and set cookies as well. 

Its weird how its not working.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code.

```
$cookie_file_path = getcwd() . '/cookie.txt';
//Emulating Chrome Browser:
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/A.B (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/X.Y.Z.W Safari/A.B.";

/*  Login part of the code -- start */

//First, get and write session cookie:
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://3dstats.com/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path);

$loginpage_html = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

//Now, use the session cookie to actually log in:
$POSTFIELDS = "type=44&usr=". $your_username ."&UsrPass=". $your_password;  

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://3dstats.com/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://3dstats.com/cgi-bin/edit2.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path);

$logon_result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

See details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333005/help-with-login-to-site-with-php-curl)